# Use Azure ML methods like an API

Tags: frameworks, rapidminer, azure-machine-learning-service

Is that possible to use machine learning methods from Microsoft Azure Machine Learning  as an API from my own code (without ML Studio) with possibility to calculate everything on their side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [publish](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-publish-a-machine-learning-web-service/) an experiment (machine learning functions you hooked together in Azure ML Studio) as an API. When you call that API in your custom code you give it your data and all the computation runs in the cloud in Azure ML.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I know that I can create experiment in MLStudio and deploy it and use as API, but my question is if it is possible to call ML methods without even MLStudio, just from my code itself?

Comment: Only if you create the experiment in ML Studio first and publish it as an API. From then on you can call the API from your code and ML Studio need never be touched again.

Comment: There are some marketplace APIs that others have built. Is that what you want of do you want to create your own API?

Comment: I just want to call machine learning methods from my code with possibility to calculate this on their side. So I mean without MLStudio at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am reasonably new to Azure machine learning but I do not believe it is possible to use their API without using the MS studio at all. For example you will need the API key to call the API and authenticate with it and the only way I am aware of that you can obtain this key is via the ML studio (after you have published a trained experiment).